# How can you ask for an alternative video input in Safari?

Tags: safari, getusermedia, snapchat, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

To get an alternative video input from `MediaDevices.getUserMedia`, my understanding is that you need to pass in the `deviceID` as a constraint. But, in Safari, to get access to `deviceID`s via `enumerateDevices`, I need to call `getUserMedia` and get permission from the browser first (maybe there's another way?). The problem is that this initial `getUserMedia` call only returns device info for devices I've given permission for, so I still don't have the deviceID of the alternative video input.

How can I get the `deviceID` for this video input?

In my case, I'm trying to find the `deviceID` for Snapchat's "Snap Camera". In Chrome, I'm able to find and stream this video input.

Comment: Desktop Safari? Mobile Safari? They're not quite the same. At any rate, once your user has granted permission for any video device, you can enumerate all video devices available to the browser. It's possible Safari can't use this Snap Camera. Apple's Safari team are playing catch-up on all this media stuff.

Comment: I've only tested on desktop. And thanks, that'd makes sense.

Comment: I see Snap Camera isn't available on Whereby calls in Safari either.